# Downside of decreasing audio latency

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, jack, pipewire

I see that with audio servers (in my case, pipewire) you can alter the "latency". (please forgive me, I am not very knowledgeable with these things.)

`PIPEWIRE_LATENCY="128/48000"`

The Arch Linux wiki described this as "request[ing] a custom buffer size".

I was wondering, is there a "downside" to setting the latency really low. Is it simply more responsive audio a higher cost of resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the buffer is small, It fills up more quickly and empties out more quickly.  This is why the latency shrinks.

However, the processes that put data into the buffer and take data out of the buffer will be triggered more often.  So you may see higher consumption of your computer's CPU by the audio software when you make the buffer too small.  In extreme cases, using the audio system with a small buffer can make the other software on your computer respond slower, or perhaps "choppy" or "stuttering" where it alternates between smooth and frozen.

A small buffer can also cause the audio stream to stutter if the process that puts audio data into the buffer can't respond fast enough and the buffer goes completely empty for brief moments.  The process that's taking the audio data out of the buffer and passing it through the output to your speakers (or headphones) will run out of data and there will be interruptions in the sound (often called "drop outs").

It's hard to predict what size will be "too small", so you may have to experiment and see what compromise gives you the shortest latency without impacting the audio streams and the rest of your computer.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I was getting some "stuttering" with my current audio parameters, so I will for sure have to experiment with buffer sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your sound application (A), whatever the sound server (B), whatever your alsa soundcard driver (C) :

- (A) will write (at its own pace PA) the samples into some buffer,
- that (B) will read (at its pace) in order to write them (at its pace) to some buffer,
- that the interrupt handler of the sound card will read (at some pace PC) into the generally fixed sized very small buffer of the hardware sound card,
- which will be read by the embedded software for echoing to the hardware outputs at a very precise pace.

From that way of working your can understand that :

- There is just no way to (imediatly) "*set the latency*". (as understood being the amount of time elapsed from the output of a sample  from (A) to the output of that sample from the hardware). Therefore… there just cannot be any *"downside to setting the latency really low"*
- The need for buffers is due to the fact that the different components involved in the process work asynchronously and therefore the buffer sizes must take into account that some(?)times some upstream component will output more (or less) samples than the immediately following component will be able to process instantly.

From the immediately preceding paragraph, and as far as buffers as concerned, you can understand that :

If buffers are undersized then, since these are most likely to be ring-buffers… you are likely to face : overruns!
That means samples that will never go their way to the hardware output, which will translate to audible clics.

So yes! There is indeed a downside in decreasing buffer sizes : **overruns**.

---

Of course there are ways to reduce that risk of overruns : Having the processes running : At the right pace !

If you can make so that downstream components can achieve their jobs right in time (or at a greater or equal pace than the upstream component) then, you can avoid the risk of overruns whatever the buffer size.

- This will start by ensuring the irq are threaded and that the real time priority of the kernel thread associated to the sound card is maximum.
- This should be followed by whatever sound server running under some real time scheduling model with a priority immediately inferior to the on of the above mentioned irq kernel thread.
- And eventually running the upstream application under a real time scheduling model too with a lesser priority than the one of the sound server.

You might also (rightly) consider that the sound server with its two buffers is just costly (in terms of additional latency) and possibly… serving no purpose and… think about just getting rid of it.